# Adding Label programmatically in tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) in custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I would like to add labels to custom cell at tableView(*:cellForRowAt:) in Custom cell. The cell originally contains 4 labels in stackview of custom cell.
After that I add 2 labels to the same stackview via code at tableView(*:cellForRowAt:). Normally, it was ok at first run.[Stage of customcell at first run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWR3z.jpg).

If I go into other viewController and come back to this tableviewController, the code added up 2 more labels. This keep repeating whenever I swtiched to other viewcontoller.[Label adding up in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4C9N.jpg)

May I know correct way for implementing the customcell and add label to customcell based on some properties of UIViewController? This UIViewController has a String array to decide how much labels should be added to customcell.

Feel free to point me out if I need to edit the question.

Comment: I guess you have an issue because of reuse. From what I guess, you are calling `addSubview()` in `tableView(:cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: *"I would like to add labels to custom cell at tableView(:cellForRowAt:) in Custom cell."* - that's a contradiction. A custom cell should already have the labels it needs. The only thing you should do in `cellForRowAt` is to create the cell and give it data. If you are calling `addSubview` in `cellForRowAt` then you are doing it incorrectly.

Comment: This is a sample of how I add the label to cell at tableView(:cellForRowAt:) in Custom cell.  I know this is a violation. I will get back on Monday after testing out. I don't have mac to test at the moment.  `let textLabel = UILabel()  
textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow  
textLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:  self.view.frame.width).isActive = true  
textLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0).isActive = true  
textLabel.text  = "Hi World"  
textLabel.textAlignment = .center`

Comment: And yes, I use addSubView to add label to stackview.  `self.view.addSubview(stackView)     

//Constraints
stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true    
stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: @Skron31 Please [edit] your question with all relevant details and code.

Comment: @rmaddy I will edit maybe tomorrow or on Sunday. Yeas, I understand the questions is a bit confusing to people. A quick note, the custom cell has only 4 labels initially in XIB file and connected as IBOutlet in customcellview.swift. Later, I add above codes in ViewController to add labels to custom cell, with stackview as a container.  And this is where the problem is. the added label are kept and is increased after switching to other viewcontroller and come back to original viewcontroller. I am dequeuing a reusable cell if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one way to do that is test if the views are already in stackView in prepareForReuse method. If they are not that, insert the views.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    if(stackView.subviews.filter{$0.tag == MYVIEWTAG}.first == nil){
       //ADD VIEWS
    }
}
```